# Entity Framework OneToMany updating items - Missing foreign-key value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I want to have one to many rel which i made with before config

```cs
public class Report
{
    [Key]
    public string ProtId { get; set; }
    public Assessment Assessments { get; set; }
    public ManualReview ManualReview {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Meeting> Meetings {get; set;} 
}

public class Meeting
{   
    [Key]
    public Guid MeetId{get;set;}
    public MeetingType? MeetingType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public string ProtId { get; set; }
    public Report Report{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to add new meeting if it was not found by MeetId or update is MeetId found with below code but when i add new meeting it is added to table like in this method i think something is wrong there i mean i do not get reference to Parent table which is Report table so after adding new meeting ReportProtId is null.

Also when i make migration it is creating this

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Meetings",
    columns: table => new
    {
        MeetId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
        MeetingType = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
        Date = table.Column<DateTime>(nullable: true),
        ProtId= table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        ReportProtId = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Meetings", x => x.MeetId);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Meetings_Report_ReportProtId",
            column: x => x.ReportProtId,
            principalTable: "Studies",
            principalColumn: "ProtId",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
    });
```

Method to add/update meetings

```cs
[HttpPut ("meetings/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateMeetings (string id, [FromBody] Meeting data)
{
    var meeting = await _liteContext.Meetings.FirstOrDefaultAsync (m => m.MeetId == data.MeetId);

    if (meeting == null) {
        var newMeeting = new Meeting {
       
        MeetId = new Guid (),
        MeetingType = data.MeetingType ?? null,
        Date = data.Date ?? null,
        };
        _liteContext.Meetings.Add (newMeeting);
    }
    if (meeting != null) {
       
        meeting.MeetingType = data.MeetingType;
        meeting.Date = data.Date;

        _liteContext.Meetings.Update (meeting);
    }
    try {
        await _liteContext.SaveChangesAsync ();
        return NoContent ();
    } catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) {

        throw new Exception ();
    }
}
```

EDITED

```
[HttpGet("lite")]
        public async Task<dynamic> GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                var data = await _liteContext.Reports
                    .Include(a => a.Assessments)
                    .Include(m => m.Meetings) // empty array
                    .Include(mr => mr.ManualReview)
                    .ToListAsync();

                return data;
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating new Meeting, set the `ProtId` value -

```cs
var newMeeting = new Meeting { 
     
    MeetId = new Guid (),
    MeetingType = data.MeetingType ?? null,
    Date = data.Date ?? null,
    
    // Add this one
    ProtId = data.ProtId    
};
```

I hope you are receiving it from the client.

**Edit :**
According to your migration code, the `Meetings` table has two columns `ProtId` and `ReportProtId`. But your model class definition for `Meeting` shows only the `ProtId` property.

If you do have a `ReportProtId` property in `Meeting` class, set the value for that property (not for `ProtId`) since you have defined `ReportProtId` column as the foreign-key, not `ProtId`.

If the `Meeting` class in fact doesn't have the `ReportProtId` property then you need to update your Migration code and update the database accordingly.

**Edit-2 :**
If you haven't defined any configuration for your model classes in the `OnModelCreating` method of your `DbContext` class, then Migration will use Entity Frameworks' default naming convention to generate the tables and columns.

According to the naming convention, the foreign-key property in your `Meeting` class should be named `ReportId`. Since Entity Framework didn't find that property, it generated one for you to use as foreign-key -

`Referenced class name (Report) + Primary-key name of referenced class (ProtId) = ReportProtId`

That's how you ended up having the `ReportProtId` column in your Migration code (and hence in the database) even though you don't have that property in your model class.

You can still use `ProtId` as foreign-key if you want, but then you have to let Entity Framework know you in fact want that property as foreign-key, even if doesn't conform to the naming convention. You can do that by add the `[ForeignKey("Report")]` attribute to it.

So, change your `Meeting` class definition either to -

```cs
public class Meeting
{   
    [Key]
    public Guid MeetId{get;set;}
    public MeetingType? MeetingType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public string ReprotId { get; set; }    // Modified
    public Report Report{ get; set; }
}
```

or to -

```cs
// this import will be required
// using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Meeting
{
    [Key]
    public Guid MeetId { get; set; }
    public string MeetingType { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Report")]                   // Added
    public string ProtId { get; set; }
    public Report Report { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ok i added this but then when i make .Inculde() to load realted data is returing empty array of meetings

Comment: @Exc Please check the Edit.

Comment: but why my migration added this column based on my relations? I was not configuring that

Comment: @Exc I might tell if you could you share the model configuration code where you defined the relationship between `Meeting` and `Report`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221536/discussion-between-atiyar-and-exc).

Comment: @Exc Please check Edit-2

Answer (score 1):

ReportProtId column in Meetings table is nullable and in your UpdateMeetings method while adding a new Meeting you are only assigning MeetId, MeetingType, and Date to newMeeting object and your ReportProtId is null while adding. Assign ReportProtId to newMeeting object like this:

```
 if (meeting == null) {
                var newMeeting = new Meeting {
               
                MeetId = new Guid (),
                MeetingType = data.MeetingType ?? null,
                Date = data.Date ?? null,
                ReportProtId = data.ReportProtId
                };
                _liteContext.Meetings.Add (newMeeting);
            }
```

Comment: ok i added this but then when i make .Inculde() to load realted data is returing empty array of meetings

Comment: i cannot add ReportProtId  becasue it was aded during migraion but my class doesn't have that prop